# Organize container content by container height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that has 2 containers that each have a bunch of content that is related. The organization of what content goes in what container is important, but not as important as the containers being as close as possible in height.

## Code:

```
<button>Click to add more boxes</button>
<div id="wrapper" align="center">
    <div id="container1">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ULxnj/2/)

---

## Question:

You will see after adding more items, only sometimes will one container have significantly more content than the other, but it does happen.

When that happens I would like to take the left over items in the larger container, and distribute them to the containers in a way that would make the heights of each container as close as possible to eachother.

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: +1 for the interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard algorithm `Subset Sum Problem` for solving this.

Problem says

```
You have n integers. Divide n integers into two sets such that |Set1| - |Set2| is minimum. where |Set(i)| represents the sum of elements in ith set.
```

I see you have a similar problem here. Assume your containers as two sets and each box height as an integer which is going to be put in that set. Problem is we have to divide the integers (boxes) in such a way that heights of two containers remain minimum.

Relevant Links:

[Subset Sum Problem - Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

[Geeks for Geeks tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/) -  Good One

Comment: That is not what I want to do. I don't want to rearrange the whole thing to minimize the hights...that would be easier to wrap my head around and code...I want to detect when one is significantly larger, and then take the extra elements in the larger container and split those in a way that the containers are then as close as possible...does that make sense?

Comment: @RyanSaxe Yes, I agree with your question but this decision which boxes need to be moved to balance the height difference has to be taken and this algorithm should be used to find out which boxes should be moved. I am proposing a greedy based (Easy solution) in my next answer which seems to be Okay but not best.

Comment: I don't think you understand...the only boxes allowed to be moved are the ones that are making the larger container too large

Comment: @RyanSaxe Yes, I have done the same thing. Make sure you read and understand the code. I have moved the boxes which are making container large in size. Checkout the other solution and I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the ideal algorithm which used be used. Still some rough calculations can be done to look the containers neat.

## [Try this bin](http://jsbin.com/upacip/2/edit)

JS Code

```
var $container1 = $('#container1');
var $container2 = $('#container2');
$('.box').each(function(){
    $(this).height(100 * Math.random());
});
var move = $container1.outerWidth();
$container2.css("margin-left",move + 10);

// Let us try to minimize the height difference
var h1 = $container1.height();
var h2 = $container2.height();
var diff = 20;

var currentDiff = h1-h2;
if (currentDiff > diff) {
  alert('1 is bigger than 2');
  reArrange($container1, $container2, Math.abs(currentDiff), diff);
}
if (currentDiff < -diff) {
   alert('2nd is bigger than 1st');
  reArrange($container2, $container1, Math.abs(currentDiff), diff);
}

// Logic: Send the minium height box to smaller container
function reArrange(largeC, smallC, currentDiff, diff) {
    var minHeightBox = null;
    var minH = 10000000000;
  
    $('.box', largeC).each(function(){
      if ($(this).height() < minH) 
        minHeightBox = this;
        minH = $(this).height();
    });
  
    // If transfering this to other reduces the difference, transfer this otherwise returh false
  if (minHeightBox !== null) {
    var newDiff = (largeC.height() - minH) - (smallC.height() + minH);
    newDiff = Math.abs(newDiff);
    console.log(newDiff);
    if (newDiff < currentDiff) {
      smallC.append(minHeightBox);
      currentDiff = largeC.height() - smallC.height();      
      //Recursively call the method
      if (currentDiff > diff) 
        reArrange(largeC, smallC, currentDiff, diff);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: better than nothing, but it most certainly does not even things out. You said it was in the works though...Also, I could use an explanation of how you're running this only on the elements that are over the limit, because I can't find where that is

Comment: @RyanSaxe You can fine tune the difference by adjusting the value of diff in the code. Take a look at this http://jsbin.com/upacip/3/edit
 Surely it won't make things exactly event because I have used greedy approach and I have already mentioned a standard approach which you should follow if you want the best.